# Will search engines deindex the entire resource when returning HTTP 410 for a parameterized URL?

Tags: googlebot, search-engine-indexing, 410-gone, bingbot

Will the HTTP 410 response code make search engines deindex the underlying page resource? Or will Googlebot and Bingbot only deindex the URL with query it's parameters as whole?

The topic [Redirection of Spams hacked page 404 to 410 .htacess](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/141576/) contemplates using a HTTP 404 or 410 response code to tell search engines to deindex content. This is all good and well on a regular page. But the actual URL here includes query parameters "?...". We want to deindex the query parameters rather then the entire page itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure that I read it somewhere in GSE docs that a URL with different parameters is treated as different pages.  This is especially true if they have different content and canonicals.

That being the case, it should not remove the underlying page when you ask GSE to deindex a page.

However, I can't find that page right now.  But here is a quote

> Yes, those are all different URLs and are therefore different from Google's SEO perspective.
>
> However, if these URLs return the same content (perhaps just displayed/sorted differently) then you need to canonicalise the URL by setting a rel="canonical" link element in the head section of the relevant HTML document. This is to ensure that only the canonical URL is returned in the search results. For example:

From @DocRoot [Do URL parameters create different URLs from Google's SEO perspective?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/110874/do-url-parameters-create-different-urls-from-googles-seo-perspective)

However, to be sure, I have converted most of my URLs to paths that are rewritten to params for the code.